# interrupted download from vagrantcloud

Tags: vagrant

I'm using Ruby 2.1.1 and Vagrant 1.6.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. Running:

```
vagrant box add chef/centos-6.5
```

I keep getting:

```
==> box: Box download was interrupted. Exiting.
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The
output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

x Vagrantfile
x box.ovf
x metadata.json
x packer-centos-6.5-x86_64-disk1.vmdk: truncated gzip input
bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

I did a wget -c [download URL] a few times to continue the download manually. Now I'm not sure how to tell vagrant to use the completed virtualbox.box image instead of trying a new download. Putting it in place in .vagrant.d/boxes/vagrantcloud.com/chef/centos-6.5/version/1/provider didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've already manually downloaded the box [centos-6.5](http://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/virtualbox/opscode_centos-6.5_chef-provisionerless.box), you can tell vagrant to use the local box instead of downloading from a URL.

Do

`vagrant box add centos-6.5 /path/to/opscode_centos-6.5_chef-provisionerless.box`

and start from there.

Comment: Link opscode_centos is access defined. How can I download it?

<code>
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DBY7ZP0QMGZ7N9RD</RequestId>
<HostId>dGzdZvMCHfNtLRFCC4c6E5GWXYsFsYhf30HQdsSUHBE4eDrXkSOq9/LfqiRzJLZKNuoXvzmnBQU=</HostId>
</Error>
</code>

Answer (score 0):

You must first run:

```
vagrant init chef/centos-6.5
```

https://vagrantcloud.com/chef/centos-6.5